# Include jsp file into dynamic html page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a dynamic HTML page as following. I send HttpSerletRequest and get response. According to that response this html content varying.

In my servlet:

```
try {
        String[] return_array = initCall(urlParameters);
        if (Integer.parseInt(return_array[0]) == 0) {    //success
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
            switch (Integer.parseInt(return_array[1])) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:{
                    break;
                }

                case 4:  //Agent
                    System.out.println("AGENT");
                    //rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/agentMenu.jsp");

                    out_str = "<html>\n"
                            + "<head>\n"
                                /*+ "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
                                + "document.onload=\"agentMenu()\"\n"
                                + "</script>\n"*/
                            + "<script src=\"js/robicash.js\">\n"
                            + "</script>\n"
                            + "</head>"
                            + "<body align=\"center\" type=\"text/javascript\" onload=\"agentMenu()\">\n"


                            + "<h2>RobiCash</h2>\n"
                            + "<div id=\"content\">\n"
                                /*+ "<h3>Agent Main Menu</h3>\n"
                                + "<table align=\"center\">\n"
                                + "<tr><td>1:</td><td><a href=\"\" onclick=\"topUp()\">Top-Up/Recharge (P2)</a></td></tr> \n"
                                + "<tr><td>2:</td><td><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"billPayment()\">Bill Payment</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>3:</td><td><a href=\"agent_2.htm\">Bill Check</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>4:</td><td><a href=\"agent_3.htm\">Cash IN (P2)</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>5:</td><td><a href=\"agent_4.htm\">Cash OUT (P2)</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>6:</td><td><a href=\"agent_5.htm\">Customer Registration</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>6:</td><td><a href=\"agent_6.htm\">My Balance</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>7:</td><td><a href=\"agent_7.htm\">More</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "<tr><td>8:</td><td><a href=\"index.jsp\">Exit</a></td></tr>\n"
                                + "</table>\n"*/
                            + "</div>\n"
                            + "</body>\n"
                            + "</html>\n";
                    break;
                case 5:       //DSR
                    break;
                case 6:      //Distributor
                    break;
                case 7:      //Master Distributor
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }  else {      //fail

        }
        getPostResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to add following jsp file to this dynamic html page.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>
<script>


function billPayment(){
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<h3>Select Utility Provider</h3>"
    + "<table align=\"center\">"
    + "<tr><td>1:</td><td><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"billBPDP()\">BPDB</a></td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td>2:</td><td><a href=\"agent_1_2.htm\" onclick=\"billDESCO()\">DESCO</a></td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td>3:</td><td><a href=\"agent_1_3.htm\" onclick=\"billWASA()\">WASA</a></td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td>4:</td><td><a href=\"\"\">Main Menu</a></td></tr>"
    + "</table>";

}

function billBPDP(){
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<h3>BPDB Payment</h3>"
    + "<form action=\"BPDBServiceCall\" method=\"post\">"
    + "<table align=\"center\">"
    + "<tr><td>Customer Account No:</td><td><input name=\"accno\" type=\"text\" value=\"\"/></td></tr>"
    + "<tr><td></td></p><td align=\"center\"><input type=submit value=\"Submit\"/></td></tr>"
    + "</table>"
    + "</form>";
}


</script>
```

I tried following. But it doesn't work.

```
<jsp:include page="robicash.jsp" />
```

If I use .js file instead of .jsp it works properly. But I cannot use .js file because I have to call a service as following.

In my servlet:

```
 @Action(value = "BPDPServiceCall", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", location = "/jsp/robicash.jsp")})

 public String callBPDPService() {
    //serviceName = "BPDPServiceCall";
    System.out.println("=====Inside BPDPServiceCall Method=====");

    url = url + "GetBPDBPaymentDetails.do?";
    request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

    String accno = request.getParameter("accno");
    String urlParameters = "accno=" + accno;

    try {
        //String[] return_array = initCall(urlParameters);    //comment only for debugging
        String result = sendPostRequest(urlParameters);
        System.out.println(result);    //for debugging

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

}
```

If I use robicash.js instead of robicash.jsp then service isn't call.

I am very new to java EE.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid generating html inside your java code where possible (ideally everywhere). You should create jsp template for every HTML you use. If you want to include jsp inside another jsp you can use `<jsp:include page="another.jsp" />`

Comment: Avoid generating html inside javascript like that too. Where you absolutely have to, you can use `'` in place of `\"` to make it slightly more readable.

Comment: You need to add the filenames of your files, because as it stands, nobody can tell which is  robicash.js(p)

Comment: Actually I guess your second codeblock is robicash.js(p) so why are you doing it as a JSP when there is zero java code or jsp in it? Its straight javascript. So take out the `<script>` and `</script>` and the JSP `@page` directive, make it a JS file, and reference it in HTML (don't include it with a jsp include).